# Data race при использовании shared_ptr

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В книге   `Concurrency with Modern C++` автора Rainer Grimm для вот таких строчек кода:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(2011);

for (auto i=0; i<10; i++){ 
    std::thread([&ptr]{
                        ptr = std::make_shared<int>(2014); 
                      }
               ).detach();
}
```

есть утверждение:

> The lambda-function binds the std::shared_ptr ptr in line 4 by reference. This means, the assignment (line 5) may become a concurrent reading and writing of the underlying resource; therefore, the program has undefined behaviour.

Скажите, почему поведение будет неопределенным?
На мой взгляд это противоречит [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object.

Comment: Потому что потоки могут менять один и тот же `ptr` одновременно.

Comment: Да, но я полагал что управляющий блок `shared_ptr` защищен, и в результате `ptr` после завершения потоков будет содержать последний созданный объект со счетчиком ссылок равным 1

Comment: Здесь же речь не идет о функциях-членах, как вы написали в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"я полагал что управляющий блок shared_ptr защищен"* - именно так. Только этот защищенный управляющий блок не содержится в `ptr`. А операции с самим `ptr` не защищены.

Цитата в вопросе относится к случаю, когда доступ из разных потоков производится к ранызным экземплярам `shared_ptr`, которые при этом могут разделять владение одним и тем же объектом. А в коде случай, когда доступ из разных потоков производится к одному и тому же экземпляру `shared_ptr`:

> If multiple threads of execution access the same instance of shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur;